# TortoiseSVN 1.7 Post-Update Hooks Not Working

Tags: tortoisesvn

My TortoiseSVN post-update hooks have stopped working all of a sudden. I just installed TortoiseSVN 1.7 and the 1.7.1 bugfix. Before this occurred, all of my post-update hooks were working fine. I use post-update hooks to generate web.config files for an application after I update from Subversion. My hook just runs a .bat file. This was never a problem before and I have confirmed that my hook script settings did not change. Is there something different for TortoiseSVN that needs to be done for these to work? It may also be noteworthy that my SVN server is still on Subversion 1.6 (though I wouldn't think that would change anything).

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: The 1.7 branch changes a lot of layout client-side (there's not .svn directory in every source dir, etc.) though, in this case, the server is unchanged.  The differences from 1.6 to 1.7 have broken a number of tools and scripts...

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I have heard other users for whom hook scripts do work, but I guess I may have to wait until there is some kind of bugfix. I tried deleting and recreating the script. No luck. I am planning to update my server in the next week or so to gain the performance increases with the 1.7 client. Hope that doesn't break anything too.

Comment: I did follow the process suggested on the tortoisesvn site of cleaning my working copies, installing, then upgrading.
 
It should probably also be noted that the hook scripts on working copies that I upgraded ARE working. The hook scripts are not working on a working copy that I checked out fresh with Subversion 1.7. Maybe that is the key, but I still don't know how to resolve the issue. The batch file that the hook script runs will run manually just fine. I tested running it in the command prompt from the location TortoiseSVN would be running it from.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging today and discovered that Subversion is running the hook scripts correctly. Someone edited our hook script batch file and it was erroring out. Of course we couldn't see that because tortoise doesn't let you catch the errors with a pause statement like Windows.